# Linq to NHibernate: Distinct

Tags: .net, sql, linq-to-nhibernate

I am trying to get the following SQL output using Linq-to-NHibernate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, at.Year FROM MyTable mt
INNER JOIN AnotherTable at ON at.Id = mt.AnotherTableId
```

The Name and Year properties are going to be wrapped up in a new class, so the C# code will look something like this:

```
Session.Linq()
   .Select(x => new FooBar { Name = x.Name, Year = x.AnotherTable.Year }))
   .ToList();
```

How can I get the DISTINCT keyword to appear in the sql query?

Comment: did you try .Select(...).Distinct().ToList() ?

Comment: how about .Distinct().Select(x => new Foobar(...)).ToList() ?

Comment: Are you using the old Linq2NH provider for 2.1, or are you using the new native LINQ provider in NH 3.x? If you're using the old provider, I think the issue is that the distinct operation isn't actually implemented.

Comment: This question is obsolete now - it is for the old Linq2NH provider

Answer (score 1):

Can't your try:

```
Session.Linq()
   .Select(x => new FooBar { Name = x.Name, Year = x.Year }))
   .Distinct()
   .ToList();
```

`Select` returns an `IEnumerable`, so by default it *should* have `Distinct`, regardless of whether your intellisense detects it or not.

Comment: I've tried putting Distinct() in all different positions but it has no observable effect. Running query profiler shows that the DISTINCT keyword is not being added to the sql query.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use the linq provider day-to-day, but looking around it does not seem possible.

Could you consider QueryOver?

```
 First firstReference = null;
        Second secondReference = null;
        var items = Session().QueryOver(() => firstReference)
                        .JoinAlias(() => firstReference.Seconds, () => secondReference)
                        .Select(Projections.Distinct(
                                Projections.ProjectionList()
                                    .Add(Projections.Property(() => firstReference.Name).WithAlias(() => firstReference.Name))
                                    .Add(Projections.Property(() => secondReference.Year).WithAlias(() => secondReference.Year))))
                        .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(FooBar)))
                        .List<FooBar>();
```

I hope this helps.